# SlickGrid select editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I want to make a dynamically populated html select for a select cell. I extract some information from a database which is different for every row item. The problem is that the editor loses the initial data and I don't know how to keep some data for a specific cell. Has someone done this before?

```
function StandardSelectCellEditor($container, columnDef, value, dataContext) {
var $input;
var $select;
var defaultValue = value;
var scope = this;

this.init = function() {
    $input = $("<INPUT type=hidden />");
    $input.val(value); 
    }

    $input.appendTo($container);

    $select = $("<SELECT tabIndex='0' class='editor-yesno'>");
    jQuery.each(value, function() {
      $select.append("<OPTION value='" + this + "'>" + this + "</OPTION></SELECT>");
    });
    $select.append("</SELECT>");

    $select.appendTo($container);

    $select.focus();
};


this.destroy = function() {
    //$input.remove();
    $select.remove();
};


this.focus = function() {
    $select.focus();
};

this.setValue = function(value) {
    $select.val(value);
    defaultValue = value;
};

this.getValue = function() {
    return $select.val();
};

this.isValueChanged = function() {
    return ($select.val() != defaultValue);
};

this.validate = function() {
    return {
        valid: true,
        msg: null
    };
};

this.init();
};
```

Comment: People might appreciate this link http://onmylemon.co.uk/2014/06/writing-an-editor-for-slickgrid/ it will give you a good grounding in writing editors for SlickGrid.

Answer (score 16):

A similar queations was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623161/slickgrid-column-with-a-drop-down-select-list) (this one is however not slickgrid tagged).

I did make a SelectEditor, with a flexible range of options depending on the column we are in. The reason of thinking here is that the datatype of the value you edit in a column will determine the valid choices for this field.

In order to do this you can add an extra option to your column definitions (e.g. called options) like this:

```
 var columns = [
  {id:"color", name:"Color", field:"color",  options: "Red,Green,Blue,Black,White", editor: SelectCellEditor}
  {id:"lock", name:"Lock", field:"lock",  options: "Locked,Unlocked", editor: SelectCellEditor},
```

]

and access that using **args.column.options** in the init method of your own SelectEditor object like this:

```
 SelectCellEditor : function(args) {
        var $select;
        var defaultValue;
        var scope = this;

        this.init = function() {

            if(args.column.options){
              opt_values = args.column.options.split(',');
            }else{
              opt_values ="yes,no".split(',');
            }
            option_str = ""
            for( i in opt_values ){
              v = opt_values[i];
              option_str += "<OPTION value='"+v+"'>"+v+"</OPTION>";
            }
            $select = $("<SELECT tabIndex='0' class='editor-select'>"+ option_str +"</SELECT>");
            $select.appendTo(args.container);
            $select.focus();
        };

        this.destroy = function() {
            $select.remove();
        };

        this.focus = function() {
            $select.focus();
        };

        this.loadValue = function(item) {
            defaultValue = item[args.column.field];
            $select.val(defaultValue);
        };

        this.serializeValue = function() {
            if(args.column.options){
              return $select.val();
            }else{
              return ($select.val() == "yes");
            }
        };

        this.applyValue = function(item,state) {
            item[args.column.field] = state;
        };

        this.isValueChanged = function() {
            return ($select.val() != defaultValue);
        };

        this.validate = function() {
            return {
                valid: true,
                msg: null
            };
        };

        this.init();
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need different select options for each individual field ? If so you may consider coding the value if each field itself as an object having the value and its options (e.g. "Blue|Red,Green,Blue,Black,White". You need an extra CellFormatter to show the value, and you can change the CellEditor code to get the options from the value after the "|" sign. Take care to write back the value including the option list after edit is done in order not to lose this information ...

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly modify the above SelectCellEditor to create different select options for each cell.

```
function SelectCellEditor(args) {

   .....

   // just to get the DOM element
   this.getInputEl = function() {
      return $input;
   };
}
```

Now it is easy to create a dynamic dropdown editor.

```
function DynamicSelectCellEditor(args) {
   // 1: if you already have a select list for individual cells
   args.columns.options = optionsList[args.item.id] // or any custom logic
   return new Slick.Editors.SelectCellEditor(args);

   /*              OR                */

   // 2: if data needs to be fetched from the server
   var editor = new Slick.Editors.SelectCellEditor(args),
       $select = editor.getInputEl();

   $select.html("<option>Loading...</option>");
   $.ajax({ }).done(function(list) {
       // Update select list
       $select.html(newHtml);
   });

   return editor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
for( i in opt_values ){
          v = opt_values[i];
          option_str += "<OPTION value='"+v+"'>"+v+"</OPTION>";
}
```

with

```
$.each(opt_values , function( index, value ) {
    option_str += "<OPTION value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</OPTION>";
});
```

if it is not working for you

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

In slick.editors.js,Define a new editor.

```
$.extend(true, window, {
    "Slick": {
      "Editors": {
       "SelectOption": SelectCellEditor,
       .....
      }
    }
  });
function SelectCellEditor(args) {
    var $select;
    var defaultValue;
    var scope = this;
    var s;
    this.init = function() {
        opt_values = eval(args.column.options);
        option_str = "";
        var tuples = [];
        for (var key in opt_values) tuples.push([key, opt_values[key]]);
        tuples.sort(function(a, b) { return a[1] < b[1] ? 1 : a[1] > b[1] ? -1 : 0 });
        var length = tuples.length;
        while (length--) option_str += "<OPTION value='"+tuples[length][0]+"'>"+tuples[length][1]+"</OPTION>";

        $select = $("<SELECT tabIndex='0' class='editor-select'>"+ option_str +"</SELECT>");
        $select.appendTo(args.container);
        $select.focus();
    };

    this.destroy = function() {
        $select.remove();
    };

    this.focus = function() {
        $select.focus();
    };

    this.loadValue = function(item) {
        defaultValue = item[args.column.field];
        $select.val(defaultValue);
    };

    this.serializeValue = function() {
          return $select.val();
    };

    this.applyValue = function(item,selectedIndex) {
        if($.isNumeric(selectedIndex))
            item[args.column.field] = parseInt(selectedIndex);
        else
            item[args.column.field] = selectedIndex;
    };

    this.isValueChanged = function() {
        return ($select.val() != defaultValue);
    };

    this.validate = function() {
        return {
            valid: true,
            msg: null
        };
    };

    this.init();
}
```

Then, modify your grid options

```
var grid_options = {
editable:             true,
enableAddRow:       false,
multiColumnSort:    true,
explicitInitialization: true,
 dataItemColumnValueExtractor: function(item, columnDef) {
 if(columnDef.editor == Slick.Editors.SelectOption){
    return eval(columnDef.options)[item[columnDef.field]];
  }else{
    return item[columnDef.field];
  }
}
```

};

And use the editor while columns initialization.

```
{id: "currency_id", name: "Currency *", field: "currency_id", editor: Slick.Editors.SelectOption, options: { 1: 'Dollar', 2: 'Yen', 3: 'Rupiah' }, sortable: true,width: 234}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments yet, but I need to add something to HeiN's answer.

HeiN's answer works great, but I have data coming in that does not match my select options and I need to still display that data... so I have had to modify             dataItemColumnValueExtractor in the options. This allows my original data to display if I do not have an option in the list to match.

```
        dataItemColumnValueExtractor: function(item, columnDef) {
            if(columnDef.editor == Slick.Editors.SelectOption){
                return eval(columnDef.options)[item[columnDef.field]] != null ? eval(columnDef.options)[item[columnDef.field]] : item[columnDef.field];
            }else{
                return item[columnDef.field];
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps somebody later down the line.