# A simple SlickGrid DropDown select list celleditor

Tags: coffeescript, slickgrid

I want the simplest possible solution for editing a value in a slickgrid using a standard html select list.

There are lots of answers here on stackoverflow all of which tell you to implement your own `SelectCellEditor`. Here are some examples:

- [Slickgrid, column with a drop down select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2623161/776476)
- [SlickGrid select editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3211956/776476)
- [slickgrid custom dropdown editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12512178/776476)

But these examples are all in javascript and are therefore a little verbose.

So I am going to answer my own question with a stripped-down CoffeeScript version. It works fine for simple select lists and is easy to extend when you want to get fancy.

Comment: That is actually a good case of asking and answering your own question, I think. Why nobody picked it up before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Simple SlickGrid SelectCellEditor in CoffeeScript**

```
class SelectCellEditor 
    last=undefined
    constructor:(@args) ->
        options = @args.column.options.split(",")
        @select=$("<select/>")
        .append("<option value=\"#{o}\">#{o}</option>" for o in options)
        .appendTo(@args.container)
        .focus()

    loadValue: (item) -> 
        last = item[@args.column.field]
        @select.val last

    serializeValue  : -> @select.val()
    destroy         : -> @select.remove()
    focus           : -> @select.focus()
    isValueChanged  : -> @select.val() isnt last
    validate        : -> {valid: true, msg: null}
    applyValue      : (item, state) -> item[@args.column.field] = state
```

**Usage**

Using the slickgrid `columns` definition, the `SelectCellEditor` is applied via the `editor` attribute with the list of select items supplied using an `options` attribute, as shown below:

```
columns = [
    // Other slickgrid columns ...
    { 
        id      : "colour", 
        name    : "Colour", 
        field   : "Colour", 
        options : "Red,Green,Blue", 
        editor  : SelectCellEditor
    }
]
```