# Slickgrid: Custom editor to store different data than that displayed

Tags: slickgrid

I've written a custom editor for Slickgrid which shows drop down box with items from sql db. These items are in the formal [id] [text]

I wish to store the [id] into the slickgrid data, but show the [text] to the user. There doesn't appear to be a callback for "display" rather than "store", so not sure how to do this? Hopefully I don't have to write a custom renderer as well?

eg.

```
this.init = function () {
                        $select = $("<SELECT tabIndex='0' class='editor-result'><OPTION value='1'>Passed</OPTION><OPTION value='0'>Failed</OPTION></SELECT>");
                        $select.appendTo(args.container);
                        $select.focus();
                    };

this.serializeValue = function () {
                        return $select.val();
                        };

this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
                        item[args.column.field] = state;
                        };
```

Comment: See this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211956/slickgrid-select-editor/21744983#21744983)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that yes, I do have to add a custom renderer (or rather, a formatter), but it's quite simple, so not so bad:

```
function ResultFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    return value ? "Passed" : "Failed";
  }
```