# Permanent drop-down menu in Slickgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I have seen other examples of this here, which have been very useful, IE:  [Slickgrid, column with a drop down select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2623161)

However, this code does not present a drop down box all the time, the select box is only visible when you go to edit the cell. How do I create a cell that has the selection box displayed at all times? Just having the text options doesn't give the user an idea that it can be edited.

Many thanks.

Comment: You need a CellFormatter