# SilkGrid Restriction the datepicker

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-ui, slickgrid

Particular cell i am giving the option for date Picker 
I want to restrict the Date picker Between tow date Ex: between '12/20/2019' to '01/08/2020'/Current Date

```
{id: "prstDt", name: "Reading Date", field: "prstDt",minWidth: 100, editor: Slick.Editors.Date}
```

This silk Grid Date don't have any restriction, all date accepting [image]

Comment: You can add an extra property to your column definitions and use them in the Editor. You might have to use your own custom Editor though. You can see an example of this implementation with a Select dropdown Editor in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3982882/1212166)

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker in Slickgrid is just the jQueryUI datepicker, so you can Google customization of dates in that. It appears that you'd have to modify the editor to disallow certain date ranges. See comment by @Ghiscoding.